# Question on Stone's Theorem : skewadjoint operator and closedness

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

So, I'm studying at the moment the following theorem and I can't understand how the closedness of $A$ follows. I can see why the adjoint is closed but how the fact that the operator is skewadjoint yields the closedness of $A$?

Any help or hint is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which book are you studying?

Comment: @VictorHugo they are lecture notes, based on Engel-Nagel book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the operator is skewadjoint, $A=-A'$. Since $A'$ is closed the closedness of $A$ follows.

If $B$ is closed then also $-B$ is closed.

Comment: so, if $-A$ is closed the same holds for $A$? I don't know but my brain got stuck to this

Comment: Yes, in general, the closedness is invariant by multiplication by a scalar. You can see this easily using the sequential characterization.

Comment: I just did. I'm stupid. thanks